# Arguments/variables in Bash script function

Tags: bash

```
arg="$@"
firstChar=$("$arg" | cut -c 1)
```

It results as "x: command not found" where x is the provided argument, $@. Why doesn't this work?

Just needs to get the first letter of the argument (only one is given).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon, and the [Ask] page too.  You talk about a Bash function; you've not shown a Bash function — maybe you meant script, also mentioned in the title.  You've not shown how the code is invoked — it appears that you passed an argument `x` to it, and you don't have a program called `x` on your machine.  Maybe you meant `firstChar=$(echo "$arg" | cut -c 1)`?  But if it is Bash, you can do better with [parameter expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) such as `firstChar="${arg:0:1}"`.

Comment: Assigning `$@` to a single parameter defeats the purpose of using `$@`. Either `$1` would be sufficient, or your code is, in fact, broken. What is the expected value of `$@`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix your script, second line has issue. Here is the corrected one that works ..

```
arg="$@"
echo $arg
firstChar=(`echo "$arg" | cut -c 1`)
echo $firstChar
```

Comment: Oh my god thank you. I've been trying random things for the past like 3 hours. Bash's syntax is god awful.

Comment: Making `firstChar` an array seems odd at best.

Comment: Unfortunately this is broken and semantically wrong. Broken: try it with an argument equal to `-n`, `-e` or `-E` or a newline (`$'\n'`) — fix this by replacing `echo` with `printf`. It's semantically wrong since you're creating an _array_ `firstChar`…

Answer (score -1):

You should use eval to execute code stored in variable

```
arg="$@"
firstChar=$(eval "$arg" | cut -c 1)
```